# mapvalues in plyr gives unexpected output when "to" argument is a factor...is it a bug?

Tags: r, plyr

When I use mapvalues in the plyr package (plyr v1.8, R v2.15.1 Roasted Marshmallows), I get an odd result when the "to" argument is a factor. For example,

```
v1 = c(1,2,2,1,2)

mapvalues(v1, from = c(1, 2), to = factor( c('A', 'B') ) )
```

returns

```
[1] 1 2 2 1 2
```

instead of

```
[1] A B B A B
Levels: A B
```

To me it looks like it might be a bug, but I wanted to check with other people before bothering the developer. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This most likely isn't a bug.  Factors are stored internally as integers.  If you have a factor and want to map to the levels of the factor instead of the internal integer storage value you can call `levels` on the factor first.

```
mapvalues(v1, from = c(1, 2), to = levels(factor(c('A', 'B'))))
```

If you want the result to be a factor then just call `factor` on the result afterward.

Comment: That makes sense. It's not a bug.

Comment: Although, I do think a warning might still be helpful -- vectors seem to unintentionally get silently converted into factors despite my best efforts. Is it just me?

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the `factor()` from `mapvalues()`. Conversion to factor can be done after value replacement.

```
v1<-mapvalues(v1, from = c(1, 2), to = c('A', 'B')) 
#Now convert to factor
v1<-as.factor(v1)
v1
[1] A B B A B
Levels: A B
```