# r plyr mapvalues with factors / dataframes shows numbers as result

Tags: r, plyr

Linked to my former question : [r plyr revalue limitation of number of operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24965843/r-plyr-revalue-limitation-of-number-of-operations)
And this request as well : [mapvalues in plyr gives unexpected output when "to" argument is a factor...is it a bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15516597/mapvalues-in-plyr-gives-unexpected-output-when-to-argument-is-a-factor-is-it)

I want to change the values of levels in a dataframe factor and I have in one factor, 300 levels to rename, and in the other, 3000 levels. So using c("", "") is out of question. I have created two new dataframes for the renaming purposes with the values to match and the values to revalue to. Now I'm stuck with a little problem that my current level of R skills lacks to solve.

Let's reuse the R cookbook example:

First create a dataframe with the values :

```
library(plyr)
cat <- c("alpha","beta","gamma","alpha","beta")
amount <- c(2, 5, 8, 3, 4)
df <- data.frame(cat, amount)

   df
    cat amount
1 alpha      2
2  beta      5
3 gamma      8
4 alpha      3
5  beta      4

mapvalues(df$cat, c("beta", "gamma"), c("two", "three"))

[1] alpha two   three alpha two  
Levels: alpha two three
```

This works, changing one value for another, and removing the unused levels.

Let's try to use an approach with a dataframe containing all the needed values to match and their replacement.

```
val <- c("beta", "gamma")
text <- c("two", "three")
reval <- data.frame(val, text)

reval

    val  text
1  beta   two
2 gamma three

mapvalues(df$cat, reval$val, reval$text)
[1] alpha 2     1     alpha 2    
Levels: alpha 2 1
```

This replaces the value of the level with a number. I'm a bit stuck there then because I can't figure out how to adapt the solution given in the second link [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15516597/mapvalues-in-plyr-gives-unexpected-output-when-to-argument-is-a-factor-is-it) provided, to my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `data.frame` converts your characters into factors. So you can either use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` or use `as.character`:

```
# version 1 
val <- c("beta", "gamma")
text <- c("two", "three")
reval <- data.frame(val, text, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
mapvalues(df$cat, 
          reval$val, 
          reval$text)

# version 2
val <- c("beta", "gamma")
text <- c("two", "three")
reval <- data.frame(val, text)
mapvalues(df$cat, 
          as.character(reval$val), 
          as.character(reval$text))
```

Careful: Your solution with `levels` replaces "beta" by "three" and "gamma" by "two" instead of the expected replacement of "beta" by "two" and "gamma" by "three". This is because "three" comes ahead of "two" (`"h"<"w"`).

Comment: Thank you I didn't see that my solution was flawed. I tried yours but I got with my 3000 levels dataframe an "The following `from` values were not present in `x`" answer - and it lists values that I checked as REALLY present in 'x'. Perhaps a limitation of mapvalues ??? I guess I'm really stuck with that one... 
But I was thinking that it should be some standard operation in R, to properly rename levels, even if you have a big number of these ?

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example, where you get the error mentioned in the above comment. Otherwise we cannot guess what the problem could be.

Comment: BTW, I used this as well : reval$text <- levels(reval$text)[as.numeric(reval$text)] to change the factor in a character vector and I had the same error.

Comment: I've deleted my solution with levels, as I do not want other people to use it and to have unexpected errors...

Comment: So I've tried it with properly adapting it to my real case problem, and it WORKS ! This is great...